# Nav bar is not displaying In bigger screens, what is the reason?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I made a responsive web page and started from phones and small devices first then moved up to desktops view. But the problem is when I began designing how it should look on desktops and big screens I thought that I had only to make my nav bar displays again by changing this CSS line inside media queries to `#myLinks {display: block;}` or `#myLinks {display: flex;}` so it becomes visible again, yet nothing is happening. Note that the display value was set to none because in phones and tablets the nav bar could only show up by clicking the burger icon. And in desktops, I don't want the menu icon to be displayed and I want the nav bar to be displayed as a row on top of the page.

**Link to the full code inside my GitHub repository :** https://github.com/IssamAth/Waitlist-page/tree/master/src/components/navbarlogo

**Here is the CSS code for the Nav bar**,

```
#myLinks {
    display: none;
  }
  
  
  #navbarlogo {
    margin: 1rem 0 4rem 0;
  }


  .logo-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }



  nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }

  .icon {
    color: black;
   
  }



  .logo {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  li a:link {color:#FFFAFA;}    
  li a:visited {color:#FFFAFA;}

  li {
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  /* MEDIA QUERIES ================ ( For Mobiles ) ================ */

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

  #myLinks {
  }

  nav {
    margin: 0;
    background: var(--color-bg);
   
  }

  li a:link {color:var(--color-primary);}    
  li a:visited {color:var(--color-primary);}

  .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  #navbarlogo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .topnav #myLinks {
     display: flex;
  }

  .topnav {
   
  }

  #navbarlogo {
   
  }
}
```

**Here is the layout**

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}


const navbarlogo = () => {
  return (
    <div id='navbarlogo'>
      <div className="logo-menu">
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src={logo} alt="" /> 
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="icon" onClick={myFunction}>
            <GiHamburgerMenu size = '28'/>
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav class="topnav">
        <ul id="myLinks">
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Communities</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Join Waitlist</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )       
}
```

**This is how it shows when I stretch the screen and the nav bar doesn't show up**

[image]

**And this how it displays in smaller screens**

[image]

Comment: I can't tell what thing you mean when you say the "nav bar". The only difference I see in your screen shots is the menu icon (hamburger) showing or not, which also seems like tadej's answer is based on, but you say "I do not want that Menu Icon to show in bigger screens" so that can't be it. I think it must be the "Features ... Affiliates ... etc" which I see in tadej's image but I _don't_ see in either of your images.

Comment: Separately, a better way to do `var x = document.getElementById("myLinks"); if (x.style.display === "block") {...}` is to toggle a class, like `x.classList.toggle('hiding');` and have CSS like `#myLinks.hiding { display: none; }`.  That way you don't need the if-test first and your code doesn't have to know that the other style is `display:block` — what if it was `display: flex` and your javascript set `x.style.display = "block";`? If you change the display style you need to change it in both places, or you'll break things.

Comment: @StephenP yeah, I totally agree with what you said, bro. I'm still new with all of that but your comment made me understand about my mistake more and more. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHANGED ANSWER:

You should avoid changing the DOM directly if you are using React. You should instead use the api that React provides to achieve the desired functionality.
Below is a fast solution I came up with, it could probably be done better but I dont work with plain css much so this is the best I could come up with.

CSS:

```
.mylinks{
  display: block;
}

.topnav{
  display: flex;
}

.topnavhide{
  display: none;
}

#navbarlogo {
  margin: 1rem 0 4rem 0;
}


.logo-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}



nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.icon {
  color: black;

}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a:link {color:#FFFAFA;}    
li a:visited {color:#FFFAFA;}

li {
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

  .mylinks{
    display: flex;
  }

  nav {
    margin: 0;
    background: var(--color-bg);

  }

  li a:link {color:var(--color-primary);}
  li a:visited {color:var(--color-primary);}

  .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  #navbarlogo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .topnav{
    display: flex;
  }
  .topnavhide{
    display: flex;
  }


  #navbarlogo {
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './navbarlogo.css'
import logo from '../../assets/Logo.svg'
import {GiHamburgerMenu} from 'react-icons/gi'
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>


const Navbarlogo = () => {
  const [displayTopNav, setDisplayTopNav] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div id='navbarlogo'>
      <div className="logo-menu">
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src={logo} alt="" /> 
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="icon" onClick={() => setDisplayTopNav(!displayTopNav)}>
            <GiHamburgerMenu size = '28'/>
        </a>
      </div>
        <nav className={displayTopNav === true ? "topnav" : "topnavhide"}>
          <ul className="mylinks">
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Communities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Join Waitlist</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  )       
}

export default Navbarlogo
```

Comment: I do not want that Menu Icon to show in  bigger screens, hence why I set its display value to none. I want the nav bar to be displayed as a row on top of the page

Comment: Ahh my bad I did not read the question thoroughly. I have pulled your code and the navbar is showing on wider screens. I will put the screenshot in the answer

Comment: It's alright, yup it shows at first, but when you make the screen smaller and then click the menu icon, it never shows up again when you widen the screen.

Comment: Hmm.. I think the issue is in the `myFunction` function. If you are using React you should avoid making changes directly on the DOM because react has its own copy of the DOM called the virtual DOM and so your changes can conflict with the changes made by React. You should instead try to achieve this using react api.

Comment: Man thanks for the advice, that was def helpful

Comment: I was just testing the solution you have provided and the navigation bar still disappears when I stretch the screen, not sure why but the problem is still there for some reasons. Althought both ```topnav``` and ```topnavhide``` are set to display ```block``` in media queries yet the navigation bar is still not displayed

Comment: Hmm strange, for me it works fine. Are you sure you copy and pasted my code exactly? In which case does the navbar not appear? When i tested your issue at the beginning I saw the navbar did not appear only when I closed it in mobile and stretched it to desktop width.

Answer (score 0):

Even after adding this `<nav className={displayTopNav === true ? "topnav" : "topnavhide"}>` to the nav element class the display of the Navigation bar was still not showing in desktop screens. And that was because the classes that `nav` element was getting in these conditions were the classes outside the media query, hence why the navigation bar only shows up when I click the menu bar and then widen the screen. I solved this by making a new class for desktops and then I added another condition to check if the viewport is for desktops or not.

**Layout**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './navbarlogo.css'
import logo from '../../assets/Logo.svg'
import {GiHamburgerMenu} from 'react-icons/gi'
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);

const Navbarlogo = () => {
  const [displayTopNav, setDisplayTopNav] = useState(false)
  console.log(vw);

  function testing(displayTopNav){
    if ((displayTopNav  === true) && (vw < 1024)) {
      return "topnav";
    }  if ((displayTopNav === false) && (vw < 1024)) {
      return "topnavhide";
    } else if ((displayTopNav === true) && (vw >= 1024)) {
      return "newclass";
    }
    
  }

  return (
    <div id='navbarlogo'>
      <div className="logo-menu">
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src={logo} alt="" /> 
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="icon" onClick={() => setDisplayTopNav(!displayTopNav)}>
            <GiHamburgerMenu size = '28'/>
        </a>
      </div>
        <nav className={testing(displayTopNav)}>
          <ul className="mylinks">
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Communities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Join Waitlist</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  )       
}

export default Navbarlogo
```

**CSS**

```
/* .mylinks{
  display: block;
} */

.topnav{
  display: block;
}

.topnavhide{
  display: none;
}

#navbarlogo {
  margin: 1rem 0 4rem 0;
}


.logo-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}



nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.icon {
  color: black;

}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a:link {color:#FFFAFA;}    
li a:visited {color:#FFFAFA;}

li {
  padding: 1rem;
}






/* MEDIA QUERIES ================ ( For desktops ) ================ */



@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

  .newclass {
    display: block;
  }

  .mylinks{
    display: flex;
  }

  nav {
    margin: 0;
    background: var(--color-bg);
    width: 100%;

  }

  nav ul {
    display: flex;
   
  }

  li a:link {color:var(--color-primary);}
  li a:visited {color:var(--color-primary);}

  .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  #navbarlogo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .topnav{
    display: block;
  }
  .topnavhide{
    display: block;
  }


   li {
    display: inline-block;
 }
}
```

**PS** I'm putting this explanation for myself only to remember how and why I did what I did and document things. Thanks to however helped.